# AndEngine What does setOffsetCenter() function do in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I'm writing android apps with Andengine. Sorry for my question, but I'm new to andengine. What does the function setOffsetCenter() do in andengine?

Answer (score 0):

I remember to use setOffsetCenter here :

```
mCamera.offsetCenter(10, 10)
```

offsetCenter simply adds the parameters to the current center coordinates. Adding 0 has no influence at all, so the call will be useless.

Comment: Actully, I see this function in AutoParallaxBackgroundExample Andengine example
[link](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java) and I don't know what it actually does